# Running Tests using React Test Utils and error

Tags: phantomjs, mocha.js, chai

I get error when using react test utils. Following this blog post: http://blog.sodhanalibrary.com/2016/11/reacttestutils-tutorial-with-examples.html#.WoVNkqhl8dU . Can you advise what's wrong?

My test class:

```
import AzSearch from '../components/AzSearch'
import { render } from 'enzyme';
//import ReactTestUtils from 'react-dom/test-utils';
import TestUtils from 'react-addons-test-utils';

describe('AzSearch', () => {
    it('should render wihtout problems', () => {

        //define component
        //var root = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<AzSearch />);
        //Check it exists
        //expect(root).toExist();

        var shallowRenderer = TestUtils.createRenderer();
        shallowRenderer.render(<AzSearch/>);
        expect(shallowRenderer.getRenderOutput()).toExist();
    });
});
```

My package:

```
{
  "name": "npmsharepoint",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "browserify -t [ babelify --presets [ react ] ] src/app/scripts/main.js -o src/scripts/app.js",
    "clean": "gulp clean",
    "test": "mocha src/webparts/User Web Parts/src/webparts/azSearch/tests/AzSearch.test.js --require src/webparts/User Web Parts/src/webparts/azSearch/tests/testHelpers.js --require src/webparts/User Web Parts/src/webparts/azSearch/tests/dom.js --recursive"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@microsoft/sp-core-library": "~1.1.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset": "~1.1.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-office-ui-fabric-core": "~1.4.0-0",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base": "~1.1.0",
    "@types/jquery": "^2.0.48",
    "@types/jqueryui": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@types/jqueryui/-/jqueryui-1.11.37.tgz",
    "@types/react": "0.14.46",
    "@types/react-addons-shallow-compare": "0.14.17",
    "@types/react-addons-test-utils": "0.14.15",
    "@types/react-addons-update": "0.14.14",
    "@types/react-dom": "0.14.18",
    "@types/webpack-env": ">=1.12.1 <1.14.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babelify": "^8.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-beta.2",
    "browser-router": "^0.2.0",
    "jquery": "^2.2.4",
    "jqueryui": "https://registry.npmjs.org/jqueryui/-/jqueryui-1.11.1.tgz",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "react": "15.4.2",
    "react-autosuggest": "^9.3.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.31.5",
    "react-bootstrap-table": "^4.3.1",
    "react-dom": "15.4.2",
    "react-responsive-modal": "^2.0.0",
    "react-select": "^1.1.0",
    "reactstrap": "^5.0.0-alpha.4",
    "sp-pnp-js": "^3.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@microsoft/sp-build-web": "~1.1.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-module-interfaces": "~1.1.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-workbench": "~1.1.0",
    "@types/chai": ">=3.4.34 <3.6.0",
    "@types/material-ui": "^0.20.0",
    "@types/mocha": ">=2.2.33 <2.6.0",
    "@types/react-tap-event-plugin": "0.0.30",
    "ajv": "~5.2.2", 
    "gulp": "~3.9.1",
    "chai": ">=3.4.34 <3.6.0",
    "mocha": ">=2.2.33 <2.6.0"
  }
}
```

Error:

```
Module parse failed: C:\Users/React Projects/Web Parts/b2\SPWPTest\src\webparts\User Web Parts\lib\webparts\azSearch\tests\AzSearch.test.js Unexpected token (33:25)
      You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
      |
      |             var shallowRenderer = TestUtils.createRenderer();
      |             shallowRenderer.render(<AzSearch/>);
      |             expect(shallowRenderer.getRenderOutput()).toExist();
      |     });
      at C:/Users/React Projects/Web Parts/b2/SPWPTest/src/webparts/User Web Parts/temp/tests.js:109

Finished in 0.249 secs / 0 secs

SUMMARY:
√ 0 tests completed
15 02 2018 09:39:27.572:DEBUG [karma]: Run complete, exiting.
15 02 2018 09:39:27.573:DEBUG [launcher]: Disconnecting all browsers

Finished in 0.249 secs / 0 secs

SUMMARY:
√ 0 tests completed
15 02 2018 09:39:27.589:DEBUG [karma]: Run complete, exiting.
15 02 2018 09:39:27.590:DEBUG [launcher]: Disconnecting all browsers
```

Am I missing some import or module or running incorrect version of something?

Answer (score 0):

Your are missing compilers config at mocha.

The possible missing part is:

```
--compilers js:babel-core/register
```

See this [link](http://jamesknelson.com/testing-in-es6-with-mocha-and-babel-6/).

Comment: Still same thing. Removing Babel now and going to re-install to see if it makes a difference but before then I better Commit and Push...just in case ;-) !!

Comment: Did this: removed babel-preset-react and babelify from pckgjson - builds
did NOT uninstall anything - builds and serves fine
npm install babel-core --save-dev - builds fine, serves fine too
run test - still not working
npm uninstall babel-core babel-code-frame --save-dev - builds and serves fine
                                                                                                              
  npm install babel-core --save-dev - clean install again. But still same error.

Comment: Do you have the .babelrc file at your root file?

Comment: Created .babelrc file in root with: {
    "presets": ["es2015"]
}. Would this work or do I need other presets in here too?

Comment: https://github.com/unicorn-standard/react-pacomo/blob/master/.babelrc copied this .babelrc file but still same error message.